# Slow checkboxes in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

http://jsfiddle.net/RAS4P/ [Open in IE-- it's just a checkbox-- I'm using IE9, not sure about others yet.]

```
`code`
```

If you start clicking really fast, just clicking away, the checkbox can't keep up. Some of the clicks don't check/uncheck the checkbox, they just get ignored--- EXCEPT that the function attached to the checkbox (not shown in fiddle) is firing anyway, I console.logged it and found it was catching every click...but the checkbox element itself isn't changing.

Why would that happen?

This only happens in Internet Explorer, just realized.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/12/CheckBox.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, in fact, by design. IE ignores double-clicks on checkboxes because it's safeguarding its users from themselves, in case they naively try to carry over the Windows double-click-to-open methodology into the browser.

You can disable the checkbox's default operation and code it by hand to allow rapid checkbox toggling if necessary, but I found this buggy and hardly worth the trouble just to cater to IE users.

Comment: Have you found any other than JavaScript solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

my guess is this is done by design specifically for supporting touch devices. It would help eliminate any fluctuations as the finger goes on/off the check box. This is purely a theory and I have no facts to back this up just seems to make sense to me.